# Why does phosphine reduce HgCl2 to Hg but LiAlH4 / LiH reduces it to Hg2Cl2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

> Why does phosphine reduce $\ce{HgCl_2}$ to $\ce{Hg}$ but $\ce{LiAlH4}$
>   or $\ce{LiH}$ reduces it to $\ce{Hg2Cl2}$ ?

It seems phosphine has more reducing tendency.But why?

Moreover can it be predicted whether a reducing agent will be reduce $\ce{HgCl_2}$ to $\ce{Hg}$ or $\ce{Hg2Cl2}$ ?

Comment: Actually $\ce{PH3}$ reacts with $\ce{HgCl2}$ to form a mercury(II) salt called  chloridomercury(II) phosphide. see this:- http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-9509